# Continue installation of gem that breaks at certain point

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems

I need to install mysql2 gem, but it breaks at linking with "ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension". It indeed uses incorrectly -lmysqlclient_r, while it should use -lmysqlclient.

So what I do:

```
$ cd /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/ext/mysql2
$ vi Makefile # change -lmysqlclient_r to -lmysqlclient
$ make
linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.so
$ cd ../../
```

What should I do now to continue the installation from this point?

Update:
Running make install "worked" I think. however my ruby installation was so broken that I decided to start from scratch, this time with userspace install. After getting to the mysql2 installation:

```
$ make install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 mysql2.so /data/web/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2

$ rails server -d
/data/web/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `resolve': Could not find gem 'mysql2 (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
...
```

Comment: it is because after first installing the libraries needed by the gem via make install you ran the server insted of first installing the required gem :)

Answer (score 4):

After a `make`, you should do a `make install`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have to take back the acceptance. As astopanic noted, this installed the library, but not the gem.

Comment: Okay. I have just answered your question: *What should I do now to continue the installation from this point?*. :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here:
http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem_install

Starting with "If you correct the compilation errors by editing the gem files you will need to write the specification by hand." follow the example.